# Hack to hide TeamViewer dock icon, issue with restarting app

Tags: dock, remote-desktop, menu-bar, gpu

I don't like TeamViewer taking up space on the Dock. I followed [this](https://www.tecklyfe.com/how-to-hide-the-teamviewer-dock-icon-in-macos/) tutorial to hide the dock icon, leaving me with only a menubar icon, which works great. TeamViewer is set to start at login.

However, in a MacBook Pro with discrete graphics, when logging into another computer, TeamViewer forces a switch to discrete graphics, and even after logging out of said computer, it stays that way, which is of course awful for battery life.

I am forced to quit TeamViewer so I can go back to integrated graphics and decent battery life. However, if I try to launch TeamViewer again, it doesn't work -- I get a request to type my password to install a helper tool, and then nothing.

What should I do to simulate whatever procedure is performed during system boot that allows TeamViewer to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the following command in Terminal after killing the previous TeamViewer instance:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist
```

Next, I launch TeamViewer as usual. It shows up in the menu bar, as expected.

For those unfamiliar or uncomfortable with Terminal, the following AppleScript could be used, assuming TeamViewer is installed in `/Applications`:

```
do shell script "launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist" with administrator privileges
do shell script "open /Applications/TeamViewer.app"
```

Comment: +/- 0  Can you give an answer to fix the problem permanently rather than having to run this each time.

Comment: @JBis I think the AppleScript I just added to the answer may be the best that can be done. The user needs only to remember to launch TeamViewer via this script rather than the original application bundle.